# UICollectionView appears blank - cells don't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, xib

I've setup a UICollectionView with a custom cell XIB. I've setup the delegate, data source methods appropriately but upon loading the collection view appears blank with a black screen:

[image: blank]

Here is my code for registering the custom xib cell:

```
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
```

Delegate/data source methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView    {
return 2;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView  numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 4; }

-(CustomViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";
CustomViewCell *cell = (CustomViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

return cell;

}
```

I've also set the class for the custom xib cell:

[image: class_xib_cell]

EDIT:

Collection view layout is set to:

```
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(50, 29)];
[flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];

[self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
```

The 50,29 refer to the size of the actual custom view xib cell

Comment: What is your collectionViewLayout set to?  Seems like either something is wrong with that, or all your cells are transparent.

Comment: Did you add the collection controller to the window?

Comment: I added the collection view in via IB and connected to an outlet in the VC. Also set the datasource and delegate to the VC which conforms to UICollectionViewDataSource, delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You should register your custom cell's nib instead of class.

```
UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"cvCell" bundle:nil];
[self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
```

Comment: Registering classes should work fine in general, although correct, it wouldn't use his xib, so it is just alloc/initting a CustomViewCell without any content from the xib at the moment.  In those cases, all of the contents would have to be added in the CustomViewCell code.

Comment: @CarlLindberg - Are you saying I must do the above to correctly load the custom cell xib with all of its elements?

Comment: @user1686342 Yes, since you create the UI of the cell in the nib file therefore you must register that nib file with the collection view.

Comment: Ok, I've just done that but still doesn't fix the issue